# Tool for capturing stream of packets > 1024 bytes and writing to file?

Tags: networking, network-programming, netcat

I have been using Netcat and recently found out that it truncates the packets with size 1328 bytes excluding header to 1024 bytes.

I am searching for a program that captures the total size of the data-part of packets sent to a specified port and writes all of the received data to a specified file in the order it is received. Are you aware of any such program?

If there isn't any, I will create my own.

Comment: What flavor of netcat ? What protocol are you using ?

Comment: netcat (The GNU Netcat) 0.7.1; UDP

Comment: Did you try increasing the MTU ?

Comment: No, I haven't.The MTU is bigger > 1328 bytes, so that shouldn't be why Netcat truncates the packets.

Answer (score 1):

I have been confronted with the same problem,
you can add the '-j' parameter to solve it .

printf "tttt"|nc -u   -j